# Get top count in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` char(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `hwid` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lastlogin` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I want to do is get the userids with the most different hwids. Before I added hwid I could get the userids with the most different ips by using DISTINCT and GROUP BY userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  userid, COUNT(DISTINCT hwid) AS cnt
FROM    logs
GROUP BY
        userid
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
LIMIT 10
```